# Filter with similar conditions in R

Tags: r, automation

I am new to R coding and I am trying to work on a project to automate some of my reports.

May I know how to filter with several similar conditions? For instance, a machine has 3 types of error: Part A is inoperative, Part B is inoperative, Part C is inoperative.

I am hoping to filter out all of the instances that the machine is inoperative, but I do not want to write a lengthy code like:

```
x <- y %>% filter(condition == "Part A is inoperative"| condition == "Part B is inoperative" |condition == "Part C is inoperative")
```

Is there a simpler way to code? something like  x <- y %>% filter(condition == "Part A,B,C is inoperative")

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vector to `filter` dynamically.

```
library(dplyr)
filter_values <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
x <- y %>% filter(condition %in% sprintf('Part %s is inoperative',filter_values))
```

where

```
sprintf('Part %s is inoperative', filter_values) #returns
#[1] "Part A is inoperative" "Part B is inoperative" "Part C is inoperative"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the amazing `grepl` within your filter:

```
x <- y %>% filter(grepl("Part [ABC] is inoperative", condition))
```

If you want to extend you condition to Parts "D" and "E", use an hyphen:

```
x <- y %>% filter(grepl("Part [A-E] is inoperative", condition))
```

---

Fun fact: if you prefer `grep`, you can combine it with `slice` instead of `filter`:

```
x <- y %>% slice(grep("Part [ABC] is inoperative", condition))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `base R`

```
filter_values <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
x <- subset(y, condition %in% paste('Part', filter_values, 'is inoperative'))
```